# Java Regex Having Invalid escape sequence

Tags: java, regex

I am new to Regex.

I have data(String[] array) in address formart

example

```
105 MyOwn St, City, ON A1B 2C3, Canada
```

Sometimes i got it as

```
 -  MyOwn st, City, A1B 2C3, Canada
 - City, A1B 2C3
 - 105 MyOwn St, City, ON A1B 2C3
 - City, ON A1B 2C3, Canada
```

I want the following result

```
Street: 105 MyOwn St or MyOwn st
City: City
Postal Code : A1B 2C3
Country : Canada
```

^
I have used if else to check if the string size. and used some methods to get my desired result.

I want to improve my functionality.

So, what i am going to do now is, create some regex patterns and use a switch statement.

so as, i am new to regex, i tried this pattern on my complete string it does match and give me a result in 4 groups, i tried it here (http://regexr.com/)

```
Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile("^(\d+\s+[a-zA-z]+\s+\w+)[,](\s*[a-zA-Z]+)[,](\s+[a-z|A-Z]{2}\s+[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9])[,](\s+[a-zA-Z]{6})$");
```

this pattern matches my string

But when i tried it in eclipse it gives me error

```
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )
```

### I am looking for help in my pattern , why i am getting this error?

Comment: Your pattern is rife with errors.  The pattern `\d+` in plain regex becomes `\\d+` in a Java pattern, and so on for the rest.

Comment: you need to double escape the \ I believe

Comment: After fixing the pattern, you should test it to make sure it does what is intended.  You could have other problems beyond this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backslash `\` is the java escape symbol as well as the regex escape symbol.

When you use a string like e. g. `"\n"`, this is considered a line break. Just like this every `\<sign>` is a special character in a java string. When you want to have a backslash in a string, you have to escape it, getting a double-backslash `\\`

You don't want to have the java escape sequence, but the regex one, thus you need to double-escape everything:

```
"^(\\d+\\s+[a-zA-z]+\\s+\\w+)[,](\\s*[a-zA-Z]+)[,](\\s+[a-z|A-Z]{2}\\s+[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]\\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9])[,](\\s+[a-zA-Z]{6})$"
```

Answer (score 2):

No one will ever be able to maintain that regex, let alone understand it; you are better off writing a simple parser. i.e:

```
String[] addresses = ...;
for (String address : addresses) {
    String[] parsed = address.split(",");

    String str = parsed[0];
    // etc..  
}
```

You can define some more concrete rules, but this is just an example;

Comment: this is what i am using now, but i am going to check the full string with my pattern. if it matches then i will my next class to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add two backslash in order to escape your string.

This should give : `Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+\\s+[a-zA-z]+\\s+\\w+)[,](\\s*[a-zA-Z]+)[,](\\s+[a-z|A-Z]{2}\\s+[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]\\s*[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9])[,](\\s+[a-zA-Z]{6})$");`